# PHP + JavaScript countdown echo 5 seconds / 1 second

Tags: php, javascript, forms, echo, countdown

I just figured out how to use javascript to echo a dynamic countdown for my redirect page. I'm curious about how to echo "second" when only 1 second is left in the countdown, but how do I do it?

Here is my code:

```
<script>
var counter = 5;

setInterval (function()
{   
    counter--;

    if(counter < 1)
    {
        window.location = 'login.php';
    }

    else
    {
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = counter;
       }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

--

```
echo "<table><tr><td> You will be redirected in <div id=\"count\">5</div> seconds.</td></tr></table>";
```

It echos "Redirecting in 5/4/3/2/1 seconds." OC as it is, I am bothered by that S when the countdown reaches 1. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show some more of your code, where/how is the `secondS` part output? The only thing we can see here is how you output the numbers in the `<div id="count">` element

Answer (score 0):

set the "s" as a variable. if counter == 1, set that variable to an empty string, and then update your div accordingly:

```
function() {
    var plural = "s";
    if (counter == 1) {
        plural = "";
    }
    // update div
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted where your "seconds" is located I will assume that it's after the DIV. I would suggest using a few if statements in your javascript to countdown and set the innerHTML accordingly:

```
<script>
var counter = 5;
var seconds = "";

setInterval (function()
{   
    counter--;

    if(counter < 1)
    {
        window.location = 'login.php';
    }

    else
    {
        if(count <= 1) seconds = " second";
        else seconds = " seconds";
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = counter + seconds;
    }
}, 1000);
</script>

<div id=\"count\">5</div>
```